# ElasticSearch bool query for range of dates

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and looking for bool query to pass it to get the data from elasticsearch in spark scala code.

Here is my query:

Get all records for the eventName = "XXXXXX" and date between("1438367180542","1738367180542")

Could you please help me to write the elasticsearch query. Below is the one I tried but its giving error.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "1438367180542",
              "lte": "1738367180542"
            }
            }
        }
      ],

          "term": {
              "eventName.keyword": "XXXXXXX"
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] query does not support [term]",
        "line": 15,
        "col": 19
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[bool] query does not support [term]",
    "line": 15,
    "col": 19
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! As you can see your `range` query is surrounded by curly braces, but your `term` query isn't and is out of the `must` array. Simply add those and move it to the `must` array and it will work. Even better use `filter` instead of `must` since you only have filters (i.e. you're not interested in scoring here)

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "1438367180542",
              "lte": "1738367180542"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "eventName.keyword": "XXXXXXX"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val for quick response and its working perfect.